# find if polynomial has multiple roots

Tags: math, prolog

I know a root of a polynomial is called a multiple root if it is [also the root of its derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593568/multiple-root-of-a-polynomial-is-also-a-root-of-the-derivative)

I'm fairly new to prolog and I want to write a code where I have a list (for example: `[3,2,1]` for `3x^2 + 2x + 1`) as the input and I have to find if polynomial has multiple roots

To calculate the derivative I just multiply each entry of the list in its index and remove the last one. but I don't know how to compute a shared root between the two polynomials or even how to compute the root of one polynomial using prolog.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: If the polynomial has integer coefficients, you can use the [rational roots theorem](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/rtnlroot2.htm) to find some of its roots. You can also use one of [these predicates](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_an_integer#Prolog) to find the factors of an integer.

Comment: Are none of these available?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: Given a root r1, use synthetic division of the original polynomial by (x-r1) and get the next root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute the `gcd` between the polynomial and its derivative. A root is multiple if, and only if, it is a root of the `gcd`. This will likely decrease the degree, which will increase your chances of finding multiple roots.

There are some strategies to follow:

1. If the degree of the `gcd` is not greater than 2, you can use a closed formula for its roots.
2. If the polynomial has integer coefficients, you can use the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to find the rational roots of the `gcd`, if any.
3. For the general case, you could use the [Sturm theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) to separate all the roots in intervals as small as you want, which is a way to achieve infinite precision.

Comment: As I said I'm new to prolog, could you explain how to compute the gcd for polynomials? (I've wrote the code for gcd of two numbers but for now I can't see how to generalize it to polynomials)

Comment: @AlalehA Start by programming the addition of two polynomials, the product of a polynomial by a number and then the division algorithm with quotient and remainder. Once you have that, the algorithm for computing the `gcd` is the same you would use for integer numbers.